# PostgreSQL pass data from recursive CTE onto function

Tags: postgresql, graph, transitive-closure-table, recursive-cte

I have the following problem: I am trying to discover all possible paths from source node (**node_s**) to target node (**node_t**).

The format of the original table with graph edges is simple: **| node_x | node_y | strength |** , where "node_x" -> "node_y" is  a direct edge with strength of the edge being "weight".

The idea is if at any point during the exploration of the paths we discover that a node among its children has target **node_t**, we record this path and stop exploring paths from this node, otherwise continue exploration.

The simple solution was to use PostgreSQL's recursive CTE which constructs the transitive closure of the graph:

```
  WITH RECURSIVE transitive_closure (source, target, weight, path_string) AS
  ( 
   --non-recurive term
   SELECT b.node_x, b.node_y, b.strength, b.node_x || '.' || b.node_y || '.' AS path_string
   FROM best_path b
   WHERE b.node_x = node_s --source_node

   UNION

   --recurive term
   SELECT tc.source, b.node_y, least(tc.weight,b.strength), tc.path_string || b.node_y || '.' AS path_string
   FROM best_path AS b JOIN transitive_closure AS tc ON b.node_x = tc.target
   WHERE tc.path_string NOT LIKE '%' || b.node_y || '.%'
  )
  SELECT * 
  FROM transitive_closure tc
  WHERE tc.target = node_t --target_node
```

The code above will discover **all** possible paths from source node **node_s**. Only after transitive closure construction, I am able to select the needed rows of paths from source node to target node (see last SELECT statement).

Example:

best_path table has the following data:

```
 node_x | node_y | strength 
--------+--------+----------
      1 |      2 |        1
      1 |      3 |        1
      2 |      4 |        1
      2 |      5 |        1
      3 |      6 |        1
      3 |      7 |        1
      4 |      8 |        1
      4 |      9 |        1
      5 |     10 |        1
      5 |     11 |        1
```

query:

find the paths from source node = 1, to target node = 4

result:

```
 source | target | strength | path_string
--------+--------+----------+------------
      1 |      2 |        1 | 1.2.
      1 |      3 |        1 | 1.3.
      1 |      4 |        1 | 1.2.4.
      1 |      5 |        1 | 1.2.5.
      1 |      6 |        1 | 1.3.6.
      1 |      7 |        1 | 1.3.7.
      1 |      8 |        1 | 1.2.4.8.
      1 |      9 |        1 | 1.2.4.9.
      1 |     10 |        1 | 1.2.5.10.
      1 |     11 |        1 | 1.2.5.11.
```

This is not what I need. Since there is a direct edge from node 2 to node 4 (target) already, I do not need paths 1.2.5., 1.2.4.8., 1.2.4.9.,1.2.5.10.,1.2.5.11., the path exploration for node 2 should stop at the point when the path from 2 to 4 was discovered.

To sum up, I do not want to discover the paths of the node if it already has a direct edge to the target node. This means that in a recursive term of CTE, I would like to have some condition that will say the following, pseudocode follows:

```
  WITH RECURSIVE transitive_closure (source, target, weight, path_string) AS
  ( 
   --non-recurive term (as before)
   SELECT b.node_x, b.node_y, b.strength, b.node_x || '.' || b.node_y || '.' AS path_string
   FROM best_path b
   WHERE b.node_x = node_s --source_node

   UNION

   --recurive term
   SELECT tc.source, b.node_y, least(tc.weight,b.strength), tc.path_string || b.node_y || '.' AS path_string
   FROM best_path AS b JOIN transitive_closure AS tc ON b.node_x = tc.target
   WHERE tc.path_string NOT LIKE '%' || b.node_y || '.%'
     AND b.node_y = node_t 
     --will select only rows with direct edge to target

   UNION (second union is not allowed in CTE)

   SELECT those rows which do not have direct edge to target 
   AND which parents did not contribute to constructing the query above. 
   i.e. b.node_x = tc.target where there is no direct edge between b.node_x to node_t
  )
```

As a result of a query to find the paths from source node = 1, to target node = 4, I would like to have the following:

```
 source | target | strength | path_string
--------+--------+----------+------------
      1 |      2 |        1 | 1.2.
      1 |      3 |        1 | 1.3.
      1 |      4 |        1 | 1.2.4.
      1 |      6 |        1 | 1.3.6.
      1 |      7 |        1 | 1.3.7.
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

I have tried many ways already: e.g. conditions in FROM/WHERE clauses, trying to pass CTE into function, but no success.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

I have my own recursive function that achieves what I want, however, it is very slow on enormous amount of data; and PostgreSQL's CTE apparently is well-optimized, so I would like to dig into it a bit more.

Comment: What's the result if Source = 2 and Target = 5? Please append it in your question. I'm trying to perfect this query: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10395130

Comment: The first CTE will output the undesired result: 2->4 (2.4.), 2->5 (2.5.), 2->8 (2.4.8.), 2->9 (2.4.9.), 2->10 (2.5.10.), 2->11 (2.5.11.). The desired output is: 2->5 (2.5.)

Comment: I modified my answer already http://stackoverflow.com/a/10395130 It now produces 2->5 only

Comment: @MichaelBuen Thank you, testing currently, will be back with results of the tests!

Comment: Another approach on query optimization, albeit not portable to other database, works on Postgresql only, it uses DISTINCT ON: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10401572

Answer (score 2):

You can make the searching of the path more efficient if you start at the bottom. Start at the children. If you start at the parent, it entails traversing all the children; whereas if you searched from the child, it has only one parent, hence won't waste time finding the path between source and target.

```
with recursive find_parent(source, target, recentness) as
(
    select source, target, 0 
    from tbl
    where target = 9

    union all

    select i.source, i.target, fp.recentness + 1
    from tbl i
    join find_parent fp on i.target = fp.source
),
construct_path(source, target, recentness, path) as
(
  select source, target, recentness, source || '.' || target
  from find_parent 
  where recentness = (select max(recentness) from find_parent)

  union

  select dd.source, dd.target, dd.recentness, cp.path || '.' || dd.target
  from find_parent dd
  join construct_path cp on dd.recentness = cp.recentness - 1  
)
select source, target, path 
from construct_path
order by recentness desc
```

Output:

```
SOURCE   TARGET   PATH
1        2        1.2
2        4        1.2.4
4        9        1.2.4.9
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/13e6b/1

Similar to this: [How to get the parent given a child in SQL SERVER 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104977/how-to-get-the-parent-given-a-child-in-sql-server-2005)

---

This is optimized, cut recursion to parent if it already find the specific one(source).

Source = 2

Target = 9

```
with recursive find_parent(source, target, recentness) as
(
    select source, target, 0 
    from tbl
    where target = 9

    union all

    select i.source, i.target, fp.recentness + 1
    from tbl i
    join find_parent fp on i.target = fp.source 
         -- despite the name, this target is another one's source
         and i.target <> 2
)
,construct_path(source, target, recentness, path) as
(
    select source, target, recentness, source || '.' || target
    from find_parent 
    where recentness = (select max(recentness) from find_parent)

    union

    select dd.source, dd.target, dd.recentness, cp.path || '.' || dd.target
    from find_parent dd
    join construct_path cp on dd.recentness = cp.recentness - 1  

)
select source, target, path
from construct_path
order by recentness desc
```

Output:

```
SOURCE   TARGET  PATH
2        4       2.4
4        9       2.4.9
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/13e6b/16

Comment: Don't you think that it'd be better to use limiting conditions in the final query's `WHERE` clause and not to push them into the `WITH` sources?

Comment: It's better to put the limiting conditions at the root source, it's efficient. If one would put the limiting condition at the final query, the final query would have to deal with almost *seq scan'd* results, it will be slow

Comment: What makes you assume a hierarchical structure? The OP writes about `source` and `target`.

Comment: It's not hierarchical, I used the OP's data directly

Answer (score 1):

Temporary table for testing:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE best_path (node_x int, node_y int, strength int);
INSERT INTO best_path  VALUES
 (1, 2,  1)
,(1, 3,  1)
,(2, 4,  1)
,(2, 5,  1)
,(3, 6,  1)
,(3, 7,  1)
,(4, 8,  1)
,(4, 9,  1)
,(5, 10, 1)
,(5, 11, 1);
```

Query:
<sub>modified to accomodate the comment about 2 - 5</sub>

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (    -- for readability and convenience:
    SELECT 1 AS node_s   -- source_node
         , 4 AS node_t   -- target_node
    )
    , x AS (
    SELECT node_x
    FROM   t, best_path
    WHERE  node_y = node_t
    )
    , a AS  ( 
    SELECT b.node_x
         , b.node_y
         , b.strength AS weight
         , b.node_x || '.' || b.node_y || '.' AS path
    FROM   t, best_path b
    LEFT   JOIN x ON x.node_x = b.node_x
    WHERE  b.node_x = node_s
    AND    (x.node_x IS NULL                    -- no point with edge to target
            OR b.node_y = node_t)               -- except with target_node

    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.node_x
         , b.node_y
         , least(a.weight, b.strength)
         , a.path || b.node_y || '.' AS path
    FROM   t, a
    JOIN   best_path AS b ON b.node_x = a.node_y
    LEFT   JOIN x ON x.node_x = b.node_x
    WHERE  a.node_y <> node_t                   -- arrived at target
    AND    a.path !~~ ('%' || b.node_y || '.%') -- not visited yet
    AND    (x.node_x IS NULL                    -- no point with edge to target
            OR b.node_y = node_t)               -- except with target_node
    )
TABLE a;
```

Produces the requested result exactly.

I added the break condition to the initial query, too, because we can reach the target in only one step.

This happens to be much like [my answer to a previous, similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8765594/939860). All the explanation and links apply. The major additional trick here is to include an additional CTE `x` to collect the nodes that ...

> have (a) direct edge to target.

For repeated use in the break condition of the recursive CTE. It is not widely known that you can add additional (non-recursive) CTEs on top of a recursive CTE regardless of the keyword `RECURSIVE`.

Comment: Thank you, Erwin, doing tests now! Will comment later on results!

Answer (score 1):

Upon re-reading the OP's question, I come up with this solution:

**source**

```
with recursive -- this denotes that at least one CTE is using recursion

inputs as ( select 1 as d_source, 4 as d_target )
,traverse_path(filter, source, target, path, bingo) as
(
  select bp.node_x, bp.node_x,  bp.node_y, bp.node_x || '.' || bp.node_y,

    max((bp.node_y = i.d_target)::int) over(partition by bp.node_x) ::bool  

  from best_path bp cross join inputs i
  where bp.node_x = i.d_source -- filter

  union

  select tp.filter, bp.node_x, bp.node_y, path || '.' || node_y,   

      max((bp.node_y = i.d_target)::int) over(partition by bp.node_x) ::bool   

  from best_path bp cross join inputs i
  join traverse_path tp on bp.node_x = tp.target
      and not tp.bingo
)    
select tp.*
from traverse_path tp cross join inputs i    
-- if Postgresql has Oracle KEEP windowing, 
-- we don't need to use WHERE clause here     
where 
  not tp.bingo   
  or
  (
    tp.bingo and tp.target = d_target
  )
```

The above WHERE clause could be shortened to:

```
  WHERE not bingo or target = 4
```

**Output:**

```
FILTER  SOURCE  TARGET  PATH    BINGO
1       1       2       1.2     0
1       1       3       1.3     0
1       2       4       1.2.4   1
1       3       6       1.3.6   0
1       3       7       1.3.7   0
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/cdde6/55

---

Here's the result for Source = 2, Target = 5 :

```
FILTER  SOURCE  TARGET  PATH    BINGO
2       2       5       2.5     1
```

---

**Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE best_path
    (node_x int, node_y int, strength int);

INSERT INTO best_path
    (node_x, node_y, strength)
VALUES
    (1, 2, 1),
    (1, 3, 1),
    (2, 4, 1),
    (2, 5, 1),
    (3, 6, 1),
    (3, 7, 1),
    (4, 8, 1),
    (4, 9, 1),
    (5, 10, 1),
    (5, 11, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Optimized solution, no more WHERE clause on final result; albeit Postgresql-specific solution, i.e. we uses DISTINCT ON in order to pick specific row :

Given this data:

```
CREATE TABLE best_path
    (node_x int, node_y int, strength int);

INSERT INTO best_path
    (node_x, node_y, strength)
VALUES
    (1, 2, 1),
    (1, 3, 1),
    (2, 4, 1),
    (2, 5, 1),
    (3, 6, 1),
    (3, 7, 1),
    (4, 8, 1),
    (4, 9, 1),
    (5, 10, 1),
    (5, 11, 1),
    (5, 12, 1);
```

Query, first stage, shows behind the scenes (source = 1, target = 11) :

```
with recursive -- this denotes that at least one CTE is using recursion

inputs as ( select 1 as d_source, 11 as d_target )
,traverse_path(filter, source, target, path, bingo, distincter) as
(
  select                      
      bp.node_x, bp.node_x,  bp.node_y, bp.node_x || '.' || bp.node_y      
      ,max((bp.node_y = i.d_target)::int) over(partition by bp.node_x) ::bool            
      ,coalesce(
               nullif(
                   max((bp.node_y = i.d_target)::int) 
                   over(partition by bp.node_x order by bp.node_x, bp.node_y = d_target desc, bp.node_y)
                   , 0)          
               ,bp.node_y)                           
  from best_path bp cross join inputs i
  where bp.node_x = i.d_source -- filter      
  union      
  select 
      tp.filter, bp.node_x, bp.node_y, path || '.' || node_y       
      ,max((bp.node_y = i.d_target)::int) over(partition by bp.node_x) ::bool        
      ,coalesce(
               nullif(
                   max((bp.node_y = i.d_target)::int) 
                   over(partition by bp.node_x order by bp.node_x, bp.node_y = d_target desc, bp.node_y)
                   , 0)          
               ,bp.node_y)                       
  from best_path bp cross join inputs i
  join traverse_path tp on bp.node_x = tp.target
      and not tp.bingo
)    
select tp.*
from traverse_path tp
```

Output for source = 1, target = 11 : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/db290/56

```
FILTER   SOURCE   TARGET   PATH     BINGO    DISTINCTER
1        1        2        1.2      0        2
1        1        3        1.3      0        3
1        2        4        1.2.4    0        4
1        2        5        1.2.5    0        5
1        3        6        1.3.6    0        6
1        3        7        1.3.7    0        7
1        4        8        1.2.4.8  0        8
1        4        9        1.2.4.9  0        9
1        5        11       1.2.5.11 1        1
1        5        10       1.2.5.10 1        1
1        5        12       1.2.5.12 1        1
```

As we can see, the target 11, is the first row among the source of 5. How this did happen? On our DISTINCTER column, we uses ORDER BY on MAX, this is one of the rare occasions that an ORDER on MAX windowing makes sense. We just use it in order to sort our result. I tried placing the ORDER BY at the end of the query, but the database complain that it cannot use ORDER on CTE. CTE forbids placing an ORDER BY clause. But as we all know, we can influence the sorting on `OVER()` clause, so that's how our results get sorted. In the result above, among the source of 5, the number 11 sorts before 10 and 12, as 11 is our target. So when we do a `DISTINCT ON` (Postgresql-specific feature), Postgres will pickup that first line, hence it will pickup the target 11.

---

This is our final query, optimized, albeit Postgresql-specific:

```
with recursive -- this denotes that at least one CTE is using recursion    
inputs as ( select 1 as d_source, 11 as d_target )
,traverse_path(filter, source, target, path, bingo) as (
  select 
      distinct on (
        bp.node_x,            
        coalesce(
               nullif(
                   max((bp.node_y = i.d_target)::int) 
                   over(partition by bp.node_x order by bp.node_x, bp.node_y = d_target desc, bp.node_y)
                   , 0)          
               ,bp.node_y)
      )          
      bp.node_x, bp.node_x,  bp.node_y, bp.node_x || '.' || bp.node_y      
      ,max((bp.node_y = i.d_target)::int) over(partition by bp.node_x) ::bool  
  from best_path bp cross join inputs i
  where bp.node_x = i.d_source -- filter
  union
  select       
      distinct on (
        bp.node_x,            
        coalesce(
               nullif(
                   max((bp.node_y = i.d_target)::int) 
                   over(partition by bp.node_x order by bp.node_x, bp.node_y = d_target desc, bp.node_y)
                   , 0)          
               ,bp.node_y)
      )    
      tp.filter, bp.node_x, bp.node_y, path || '.' || node_y       
      ,max((bp.node_y = i.d_target)::int) over(partition by bp.node_x) ::bool  
  from best_path bp cross join inputs i
  join traverse_path tp on bp.node_x = tp.target
      and not tp.bingo
) select tp.* from traverse_path tp
```

Output for source = 1, target = 11 http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/db290/55

```
FILTER   SOURCE   TARGET   PATH     BINGO
1        1        2        1.2      0
1        1        3        1.3      0
1        2        4        1.2.4    0
1        2        5        1.2.5    0
1        3        6        1.3.6    0
1        3        7        1.3.7    0
1        4        8        1.2.4.8  0
1        4        9        1.2.4.9  0
1        5        11       1.2.5.11 1
```

---

Output for source = 1, target = 4 : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/db290/53

```
FILTER  SOURCE  TARGET  PATH    BINGO
1       1       2       1.2     0
1       1       3       1.3     0
1       2       4       1.2.4   1
1       3       6       1.3.6   0
1       3       7       1.3.7   0
```

Output for source = 2, target = 5 : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/db290/54

```
FILTER  SOURCE  TARGET  PATH    BINGO
2       2       5       2.5     1
```

---

---

Another approach, instead of BINGO approach. Use continue_search as the logic for continuing the travesal. And use EVERY aggregate function to determine if we need to continue traversing the graph.

Here's how it works: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/db290/84

Final query: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/db290/85

It's interesting to note that EVERY is very English-like as it gets:

Contrast this:

```
,max((bp.node_y = i.d_target)::int) over(partition by bp.node_x) ::bool
```

With using EVERY :

```
,every(bp.node_y <> i.d_target) over(partition by bp.node_x)
```

Which one is easier to read?

Here's the output that illustrates the principle of using EVERY to facilitate DISTINCT ON:

Source = 1, Target = 5. **Note that 5** sorts first before other numbers that belongs to the same source, this will later be picked on by DISTINCT ON.

```
FILTER    SOURCE    TARGET    PATH      CONTINUE_SEARCH     DISTINCTER
1         1         2         1.2       1                   2
1         1         3         1.3       1                   3
1         2         5         1.2.5     0                   0
1         2         4         1.2.4     0                   0
1         3         6         1.3.6     1                   6
1         3         7         1.3.7     1                   7
```

Here's the query that does that principle:

```
with recursive -- this denotes that at least one CTE is using recursion

inputs as ( select 1 as d_source, 5 as d_target )
,traverse_path(filter, source, target, path, continue_search, distincter) as
(
  select                      
      bp.node_x, bp.node_x,  bp.node_y, concat(bp.node_x , '.' , bp.node_y )
      ,every(bp.node_y <> i.d_target) over(partition by bp.node_x)          
      ,coalesce(        
              cast(nullif(
                   every(bp.node_y <> i.d_target) 
                   over(partition by bp.node_x order by bp.node_x, bp.node_y = d_target desc, bp.node_y)
                   , true) as int)
               ,bp.node_y)                           
  from best_path bp cross join inputs i
  where bp.node_x = i.d_source -- filter      
  union      
  select 
      tp.filter, bp.node_x, bp.node_y, concat(path , '.' , node_y)
      ,every(bp.node_y <> i.d_target) over(partition by bp.node_x)    
      ,coalesce(
              cast(nullif(
                   every(bp.node_y <> i.d_target) 
                   over(partition by bp.node_x order by bp.node_x, bp.node_y = d_target desc, bp.node_y)
                   , true) as int)
               ,bp.node_y)                       
  from best_path bp cross join inputs i
  join traverse_path tp on bp.node_x = tp.target
     and tp.continue_search
)    
select tp.*
from traverse_path tp
```

Final query:

```
with recursive -- this denotes that at least one CTE is using recursion

inputs as ( select 1 as d_source, 5 as d_target )
,traverse_path(filter, source, target, path, continue_search) as
(
  select                      
      distinct on
      (
        bp.node_x
        ,coalesce(
              cast(nullif(
                   every(bp.node_y <> i.d_target) 
                   over(partition by bp.node_x order by bp.node_x, bp.node_y = d_target desc, bp.node_y)
                   , true) as int)
               ,bp.node_y)                       
      )    
      bp.node_x, bp.node_x,  bp.node_y, concat(bp.node_x , '.' , bp.node_y )
      ,every(bp.node_y <> i.d_target) over(partition by bp.node_x)          
  from best_path bp cross join inputs i
  where bp.node_x = i.d_source -- filter      
  union      
  select   
      distinct on
      (
        bp.node_x
        ,coalesce(
              cast(nullif(
                   every(bp.node_y <> i.d_target) 
                   over(partition by bp.node_x order by bp.node_x, bp.node_y = d_target desc, bp.node_y)
                   , true) as int)
               ,bp.node_y)                       
      )  
      tp.filter, bp.node_x, bp.node_y, concat(path , '.' , node_y)
      ,every(bp.node_y <> i.d_target) over(partition by bp.node_x)          
  from best_path bp cross join inputs i
  join traverse_path tp on bp.node_x = tp.target
     and tp.continue_search
)    
select tp.*
from traverse_path tp
```

Output:

```
FILTER    SOURCE    TARGET    PATH      CONTINUE_SEARCH
1         1         2         1.2       1
1         1         3         1.3       1
1         2         5         1.2.5     0
1         3         6         1.3.6     1
1         3         7         1.3.7     1
```