# Mysql technique for Skill dependencies

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a question about a Database technique to store dependencies. I know there are out there a lot of them, but I cannot place them easily in the scheme I need. 
I have created simple image:

[image: Skills example]

As you can see what I need is to create a tree of skills (like in games) which depends on each other. So for example if someone goes and want to have skill 8 I can tell him that he needs to first have skill 1,2 and 5.

This might be fine for hirearchial data in database, but what I cannot quite figure out is how to do this model dynamically. The problem I have is, that skills will be added all the time in all possible places in the tree. Never ending. An skills can be added on any level.

Now after this first question there is one more complication. I need the skills to have levels as well. So for example skill 1 can have 10 levels. and you can achieve skill 2 only after achieving skill 1 level 5.

For people who play games like World of Warcraft should be understandable.

One more note, Skills can be added anytime, but cannot be changed after adding. On normal basis. Just in case some of the skill would be extremely bad or something like that, then it would be removed, but that would occur just very rarely.

Thank you for suggestions, links or any other materials!

Comment: Without some sort of stored procedure that handles looping and recursively trying to add all that qualify, it can't be done in a single query as you've noted that you never know how many levels deep the data will be going.

Comment: It doesnt have to be done in single query, I just need some technique how to achieve this

Comment: Is MySQL a requirement? That's easy on database that supports CTE and windowing function http://stackoverflow.com/a/10395130 http://stackoverflow.com/a/10401572 Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/db290/85

Comment: Yes MySQL is requirement, but the link you posted looks really good for this problem.

Comment: On your graph, 7 requires skill #6. But on your tabular results, 6 is not included

Comment: Ah My fault, sorry, I knew i will make one :) thank you for noticing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm challenged enough to solve the problem, but I'm not challenged enough to solve it in MySQL. With that in mind, here's the Postgresql version of your problem:

```
with recursive 
skill_list(skill_id) as
(
    select distinct skill_id from skill_req 
    where req is not null
    union
    select distinct req from skill_req
    where req is not null 
)
,skill_tree(skill_group, depend_on) as
(
    select skill_id, skill_id -- seeds
    from skill_list         
    union       
    select st.skill_group, sr.req
    from skill_req sr
    join skill_tree st 
    on sr.skill_id = st.depend_on 
)
,skills_required as
(
    select skill_group, depend_on
    from skill_tree
    where skill_group <> depend_on -- remove seeds  
)
select 
    sl.skill_id, 
    array_agg(sr.depend_on order by depend_on) as array_version,
    array_to_string(array_agg(sr.depend_on order by depend_on), ',') 
        as group_concat_version    
from skill_list sl
left join skills_required sr on sr.skill_group = sl.skill_id
group by sl.skill_id
```

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE skill_req
    (skill_id int, req int);

INSERT INTO skill_req
    (skill_id, req)
VALUES   
   (2, 1),

   (4, 3),

   (5, 1),

   (6, 4), 
   (6, 2),

   (7, 6),   
   (7, 9),

   (8, 2),
   (8, 5),

   (9, 3),

   (10, 4),
   (10, 5),
   (10, 9);
```

Output:

```
 skill_id | array_version | group_concat_version 
----------+---------------+----------------------
        1 | {NULL}        | 
        2 | {1}           | 1
        3 | {NULL}        | 
        4 | {3}           | 3
        5 | {1}           | 1
        6 | {1,2,3,4}     | 1,2,3,4
        7 | {1,2,3,4,6,9} | 1,2,3,4,6,9
        8 | {1,2,5}       | 1,2,5
        9 | {3}           | 3
       10 | {1,3,4,5,9}   | 1,3,4,5,9
(10 rows)
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/77894/1

Comment: Query aside, which the relevancy is debatable especially it will not work on MySQL. The design is there, how could that be irrelevant? :-) If I would create a graph of skills, that would be my database design, two fields only, so as to keep the conceptual model simple. Other auxiliary information that pertains to skills would be kept on separate tables.

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see what I need is to create a tree of skills (like in
>   games) which depends on each other.
>
> I need the skills to have levels as well. So for example skill 1 can
>   have 10 levels.

This means that you will need a table to store the skill and the max level of the skill, basically:

```
create table skills(
  skill_id integer,
  skill_name varchar(500) not null,
  skill_max_level integer not null,
  primary key(skill_id));
```

And you will need to set the dependecy with an optional level required:

```
create table skills_depend
( skill_id integer
, skill_depend integer
, level_depend integer 
, primary key(skill_id, skill_depend)
, foreign key (skill_id)
  references skills (skill_id)
, foreign key (skill_depend)
  references skills (skill_id) );
```

The query will depend on what you want to check (e.g. if the user have the pre-requisites to adquire a skill).

Combined this with the user level and the skills that he already have I think that's a start point.

> One more note, Skills can be added anytime, but cannot be changed
>   after adding. On normal basis. Just in case some of the skill would be
>   extremely bad or something like that, then it would be removed, but
>   that would occur just very rarely.

This requirement you will need to control in your application level (let the user only add or delete the skill).

---

You can play with this on the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed2f6)

Comment: Can you show me example query to get tree of a skill like i have on the picture? Let's say skill 7, Thanks

Comment: Well, MySQL don't support recursive query. You will need to do this using PHP.

Comment: but in that case I think it would be slowing down the project a lot. I still think there should be a way. For example if you look at hirearchial data structure (its somewhere around here) where you keep numbers of right and left it is possible to get the whole tree. But I just dont seem to fit that theory into my needs

Comment: "slowing down the project a lot": in how way you based this thought?

Comment: ok, lets say that I have skill which has 10 skills as requirement, all of them recursive levels. So I would get the requested skill and all nearest required skills. And then for all those I get again queries to get nearest skills etc etc. So at the end I might be calling hundereds of queries. Please share other idea