# Querying Supervisor's Supervisor in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I have a simple query that shows all employees from a view.

```
 SELECT vw_hiearchy.win_id,
    vw_hiearchy.full_name,
    vw_hiearchy.job_title,
    vw_hiearchy.current_sup_name,
    vw_hiearchy.sbu,
    vw_hiearchy.cost_center,
    vw_hiearchy.lob
   FROM app_reports.vw_hiearchy
  WHERE vw_hiearchy.attrition_date IS NULL;
```

I'd like to know how I can recursively find the current_sup_name's current_sup_name (all the way up) and possibly comma-delimiting it under a single column?

Comment: Possibly useful question: [PostgreSQL pass data from recursive CTE onto function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10392567/4519059) ;).

Comment: The recursive CTE examples [in the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) might be a little easier to follow